# When the smart group cache is regenerated, are disabled smart groups regenerated?

Tags: smartgroups, cache

I work with a CiviCRM install with about 400 smart groups - but only about 30 of them are enabled.  I'm seeing slow performance - I'm wondering if anyone knows definitively whether my disabled smart groups are affecting performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure that we only consider active groups to regenerate the cache:

CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php

also most smart groups are regenerated on demand. The scheduled job invokes the loadAll function with groupsIDs as null, which in turn restricts the query to is_active groups